# How to concatenate in R other values of same group into a column based off unique identifier

Tags: r

```
Letter Group      
    A  1    
    B  1  
    C  1    
    D  2  
    E  2
```

to become:

```
Letter Group  SameGroup  
A      1      B,C  
B      1      A,C  
C      1      A,B  
D      2      E  
E      2      D
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
df$SameGroup<-mapply(function(x,y)
                       toString(setdiff(x,y)),
                     ave(df$Letter,df$Group,FUN= list),df$Letter)  
#  Letter Group SameGroup
#1      A     1      B, C
#2      B     1      A, C
#3      C     1      A, B
#4      D     2         E
#5      E     2         D
```

**Data**

```
df<-structure(list(Letter = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), Group = c(1, 
1, 1, 2, 2)), .Names = c("Letter", "Group"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'Group', loop through the sequence of rows, subset the 'Letter' based on the sequence, convert to `list` and assign (`:=`) as 'SameGroup'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, SameGroup := list(lapply(seq_len(.N), function(i) Letter[-i])), Group]
df
#   Letter Group SameGroup
#1:      A     1       B,C
#2:      B     1       A,C
#3:      C     1       A,B
#4:      D     2         E
#5:      E     2         D
```